# .multiselect is not a function, plugin badly loaded?

Tags: jquery, plugins, symfony4, multi-select

I added a plugin for a multiselect in my Symfony 4 project.
I installed the css file in my css assets and the js file in the js assets. I loaded everything with webpackConfig.js.

```
//WebpackConfig.js : load is ok
.addEntry('multiselectjs', './assets/js/multiselect.js') 
.addEntry('multiselectcss', './assets/css/multiselect.css')
```

---

```
 /*app.js 
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
  *
  * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
  * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
  */

 // any CSS you require will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
 require('../css/app.scss');

 // Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
 // const $ = require('jquery');

 // loads the jquery package from node_modules
 const $ = require('jquery');
 global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
 // this "modifies" the jquery module: adding behavior to it
 // the bootstrap module doesn't export/return anything
 require('bootstrap');


 // or you can include specific pieces
 // require('bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip');
 // require('bootstrap/js/dist/popover');

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

     $('#my-select').multiSelect({keepOrder: true,
         selectableHeader: '<span class="multiple-select-header">Groupes disponibles</span>',
         selectionHeader : '<span class="multiple-select-header">Sélection</span>'
     });
 });
```

Until then, everything is fine, if I look at the sources of my web page, the files are correctly loaded.

I have a problem, though. When I call the function of this plugin, I have an error telling me that .multiselect () is not a function.

```
-> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).multiSelect is not a function TypeError: $(...).multiSelect is not a function [...]
-> jquery.js:3850 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiSelect is not a function [...]
```

Would you have an idea of what is badly loaded in what I did?

Comment: did you include jquery script before your multiselect script?

Comment: Yes, in my app.js, jquery is loaded before the line where I call .multiselect (). I edit my first post to put it in full.